# Consuming nested JSON message from Kafka with ClickHouse

Tags: json, apache-kafka, clickhouse

Clickhouse can definitely read JSON messages from Kafka if they are flat JSON documents.

We indicate this with `kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow'` in Clickhouse.

This is the way we currently using it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE topic1_kafka
(
    ts Int64,
    event String,
    title String,
    msg String
) ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'kafka1test.intra:9092,kafka2test.intra:9092,kafka3test.intra:9092',
kafka_topic_list = 'topic1', kafka_num_consumers = 1, kafka_group_name = 'ch1', 
kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow'
```

This is fine as long as producers send flat JSON to `topic1_kafka`. But not all producers send flat JSON, most of the applications generate nested JSON documents like this:

```
{
  "ts": 1598033988,
  "deviceId": "cf060111-dbe6-4aa8-a2d0-d5aa17f45663",
  "location": [39.920515, 32.853708],
  "stats": {
    "temp": 71.2,
    "total_memory": 32,
    "used_memory": 21.2
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the JSON document above is not compatible with `JSONEachRow`, therefore ClickHouse cannot map fields in the JSON document to columns in the table.

Is there any way to do this mapping?

**EDIT**: We want to map the nested json to a flat table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE topic1
(
    ts Int64,
    deviceId String,
    location_1 Float64,
    location_2 Float64,
    stats_temp Float64,
    stats_total_memory Float64,
    stats_used_memory Float64
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I was able to solve it using [`JSONAsString`](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/formats#jsonasstring) format. In this format, a single JSON object is interpreted as a single value. This format can only be parsed for a table with a single field of type String.

```sql
CREATE TABLE topic1_kafka (
  data String
) 
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS 
    kafka_format = 'JSONAsString',
    ...


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW topic1_mv TO topic1 AS
SELECT 
    JSONExtractInt(data, 'ts') AS ts, 
    JSONExtractString(data, 'deviceId') AS deviceId, 
    JSONExtractFloat(data, 'location', 1) AS location_1,  -- arrays are indexed from 1
    JSONExtractFloat(data, 'location', 2) AS location_2,
    JSONExtractFloat(data, 'stats', 'temp') AS stats_temp, 
    JSONExtractFloat(data, 'stats', 'total_memory') AS stats_total_memory, 
    JSONExtractFloat(data, 'stats', 'memory') AS stats_used_memory 
FROM topic1_kafka
```

See also:

- [Injecting JSON-formatted data into Clickhouse via Kafka Engine](https://yuhui-lin.github.io/post/2021-06-01_clickhouse-json/)
- [Clickhouse JSON functions](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the once way is getting 'raw' data as String and then process each row using [JSON functions](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/) in Consumer Materialized View.

```sql
WITH '{"ts": 1598033988, "deviceId": "cf060111-dbe6-4aa8-a2d0-d5aa17f45663", "location": [39.920515, 32.853708], "stats": { "temp": 71.2, "total_memory": 32, "used_memory": 21.2 }}' AS raw
SELECT 
  JSONExtractUInt(raw, 'ts') AS ts,
  JSONExtractString(raw, 'deviceId') AS deviceId,
  arrayMap(x -> toFloat32(x), JSONExtractArrayRaw(raw, 'location')) AS location,
  JSONExtract(raw, 'stats', 'Tuple(temp Float64, total_memory Float64, used_memory Float64)') AS stats,
  stats.1 AS temp,
  stats.2 AS total_memory,
  stats.3 AS used_memory;

/*
┌─────────ts─┬─deviceId─────────────────────────────┬─location──────────────┬─stats────────────────────────┬─temp─┬─total_memory─┬────────used_memory─┐
│ 1598033988 │ cf060111-dbe6-4aa8-a2d0-d5aa17f45663 │ [39.920513,32.853706] │ (71.2,32,21.200000000000003) │ 71.2 │           32 │ 21.200000000000003 │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴──────┴──────────────┴────────────────────┘
*/
```

Remark: for numbers with floating point should be used type *Float64* not *Float32* (see related [CH Issue 13962](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/13962)).

---

Using the standard data types required changing the schema of JSON:

1. represent *stats* as [Tuple](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/tuple/)

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_tuple_field
(
    ts Int64,
    deviceId String,
    location Array(Float32),
    stats Tuple(Float32, Float32, Float32)
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY ts;


INSERT INTO test_tuple_field FORMAT JSONEachRow 
{ "ts": 1598033988, "deviceId": "cf060111-dbe6-4aa8-a2d0-d5aa17f45663", "location": [39.920515, 32.853708], "stats": [71.2, 32, 21.2]};
```

2. represent *stats* as [Nested Structure](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#jsoneachrow-nested)

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_nested_field
(
    ts Int64,
    deviceId String,
    location Array(Float32),
    stats Nested (temp Float32, total_memory Float32, used_memory Float32)
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY ts;


SET input_format_import_nested_json=1;
INSERT INTO test_nested_field FORMAT JSONEachRow 
{ "ts": 1598033988, "deviceId": "cf060111-dbe6-4aa8-a2d0-d5aa17f45663", "location": [39.920515, 32.853708], "stats": { "temp": [71.2], "total_memory": [32], "used_memory": [21.2] }};
```

---

See the related answer [ClickHouse JSON parse exception: Cannot parse input: expected ',' before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65105292/303298).

Comment: What format should I specify in `kafka_format` when creating a clickhouse table with Kafka Engine?

Comment: I would try to test it for TSVRaw, TSV, CSV.

Comment: the problem is, when using CSV, if the message contains a comma, which definitely does, then clickhouse thinks its a different column. Therefore cannot parse the message. Same thing also applies for TSV, the message cannot contain a tab character.

Comment: probably it is impossible ;( , try to check each format (the full list: *select * from system.formats*)

Comment: look at [virtual columns](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka/#virtual-columns); in [Altinity Kafka FAQ](https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq) mentioned **_raw_message** - that may help (if it exist, in source code I don't see ref to it https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/84db9a3a66844b0071f787a0020b8919ea20452c/src/Storages/Kafka/KafkaBlockInputStream.cpp#L37).

Comment: _raw_message is not implemented yet :(

Comment: try to use TSVRaw-formatter - *select '{"a": 2, "b": "\t aa "}' format TSVRaw*

Comment: Interestingly, while TSV and CSV works as `kafka_format`, TSVRaw doesn't seem to work. Investigating...

Comment: [Opened and issue](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/14035) for this.